# Setting up a trigger for a Google add-on using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have built an add-on to check for submissions to Google Classrooms within my domain. I want to trigger running this every weekend. Here is the code:

```
  try{
    var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }

    ScriptApp.newTrigger('trigger_submissions_check')
    .timeBased()
    .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.SUNDAY)
    .atHour(0)
    .create();
    Browser.msgBox("Successfully created a trigger");
  } catch(e) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("xxx@yyy.zzz","Classroom Project EXCEPTION in Trigger", e.message);
  }
```

When I run this code as a separate user, a trigger is installed, but it doesn't run. No exceptions, no messages. This is what I see in the listed triggers:
[image: trigger listing screenshot]

I have gone through [this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#installable_triggers_in_add-ons) and [this link](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-triggers#installable_triggers). Is there a way to get this to work? Or, do I need to write the trigger in the manifest as that second link suggests?

Comment: Maybe try putting `atHour(0)` *before* `.onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.SUNDAY)`?    Editor add-ons do have restrictions for time-based triggers, (see: [https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers#restrictions_2](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers#restrictions_2)) but it should be able to run once a week.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This code worked. Just that it got triggered at 00:48. [This link](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) says that "The time may be slightly randomized". So it runs anytime within the hour.